# how exactly module async.seq to make a code run sequentially?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Recently, i was using module **async** and module **cheerio** in my node.js code.
What i want to do is **get each value of the array: array1**, so i use the seq method of module async to make the code execute sequentially, then i can  get each value of the array:array(name). but my code did't work, i dont know what is the problem.

Document of module **async** is here:https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-seq#seq

Can somebody help me how can i solve the problem?Thank you!

```
async.seq(    // module async
       function(callback) {
              $('.class').each(function(i, elem) {    // module cheerio
                    array1[i] ='a';
              });
              callback(array1);
       },
       function(array1){
           console.log(array1[0]);
       }
);
```

Comment: You don't seem to do anything asynchronous here - there's no reason to use `asnyc` instead of a simple loop.

Comment: @Bergi , No, i need to get the values of array1 in the end, but you know sequence of this code is always asynchronous, so i get the array first, and then assign, at that that, it was too late

Comment: Which sequence in the code is asynchronous? The `async.seq` callback is synchronous. Is this `$('.class').each(…)` thing asynchronous? It does seem to take callback or return a promise.

Comment: @Bergi yes, I am agree with you, but i need to find a way to solve this problem.

Comment: It would help if you could answer my questions :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need execute seq method:

```
async.seq(
    function(callback) {
        var array1 = {};
        $('.class').each(function(i, elem) {
            array1[i] = 'a';
        });
        callback(null, array1);
    },
    function(array1, callback) {
        callback(null, array1[0]);
    }
)(function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g26h8772/1/

Comment: i try it, but it always run  callback(null, array1); and then  callback(null, array1[0]); and console.log(data);   in the end is:array1[i] = 'a';    I think it is the problem of  $('.class').each();